# Criminal behavior by US Diplomatic appointees?

Tags: international-relations, president, financing

[image: Howard Gutman]
Aside from Obama fundraiser,  [Howard Gutman](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-news/3030484/posts) (Pictured Above, the one who is not a smurf)

Anything along the lines of [The Vaticans?](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/08/25/josef-wesolowski-sex-abuse_n_5710819.html).

Are there any examples of sexual or criminal scandals amongst any contemporary presidents choices for Ambassador?

Comment: I'm Not sure why people are voting this down, as I'm asking about 'accusations', guess I should point out that Gutman denied these accusations. This is a serious political science question, not trolling or trying to pursue an agenda.

Comment: Well, for one thing, it doesn't seem to be a **question**, as asked. The picture has nothing to do with the content.

Comment: Are you asking if there has ever been a sexual or criminal scandal committed by the tens of thousands of US diplomats over hundreds of years? Because I'd be shocked if the answer was no.

Comment: Howard Gutman was the US Ambassador to Belgium, he resigned, along with Hillary Clinton, over accusations of soliciting child prostitutes in the park. Directly, relevant.
 Basically, I'm trying to determine the track record of shielding, or not, US State Dept. employees from prosecution.

Comment: Some would ask if there were any that were not involved with criminal behavior...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Randall L. Tobias was the U.S. Ambassador of the U.S. Agency for Intentional Development and the deputy Secretary of State under George W. Bush. He was forced to resign after it came to light he had used an [infamous D.C. prostitution service](http://blogs.abcnews.com/theblotter/2007/04/senior_official.html) (the same service, incidentally, that would destroy New York Governor Eliot Spitzer's political career).

The Russian press reported that Bush's Ambassador to Azerbaijan [Reno Harnish](http://english.pravda.ru/world/ussr/20-04-2006/79381-azerbaijan-0/) was recalled because of his involvement in a prostitution and human trafficking scandal in that country. No allegations were ever proven, and given the Russian government's heavy influence in the media, those allegations should probably be taken with a grain of salt.

In recent years, it's true that U.S. ambassadors have often been [embarrassments](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/politics/2014/02/5-most-cringe-worthy-blunders-from-obamas-ambassador-nominees/). The advent of lightning-fast communication channels have made the entire purpose of ambassadorship largely ceremonial, so ambassadorships to close U.S. allies are typically given to unqualified party loyalists. Barack Obama is not the first president to do so, and I doubt he'll be the last.

Comment: Perfect, because of the secretive nature, it is somewhat difficult to find information that is not politically biased, or conspiratorial in nature. I suspect that the DoS covers this up, more often than not.